# Symfony/PUGXMultiUserBundle separate sessions/cookies for two types of users logged at the same time?

Tags: php, symfony, session, cookies, pugxmultiuserbundle

Symfony2.8 with PUGXMultiUserBundle: I've got multiple user types (separate entities) and one login form. Users are redirected to different "subsystems", based on user entity type.
And now client wants the sessions to be separate, so in two browser windows/tabs it should be possible to login with two users of different types. Is it even possible without creating separate subdomains for each subsystem?

Comment: I don't think that is possible due to shared session cookie `PHPSESSID`. Only different subdomains could help in this case, as far as I know...